# Bootstrap Modal Overlay not cover Layout page in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap Modal in ASP.Net MVC Project, it work fine but the problem that the Overlay of Modal cover only the page but not layout page and Navbar, 
I have layout page and i am using modal in sub page

```
<!-- The Modal -->
            <div id="myModal" class="modal">

                <!-- Modal content -->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
                        <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: Use you browser tools to inspect the css (most likely a `z-order` issue)

Comment: Give z-index greater than navbar for overlay.